# CKFinder 3 adds extra / in path

Tags: javascript, php, ckeditor, ckfinder

I've defined some resource types in CKFinder 3. From my `config.php`, here are the back end and resource type definitions:

```
$config['backends'][] = [
    'name' => 'default',
    'adapter' => 'local',
    'baseUrl' => '/images',
    'root' =>     '/var/www/mysite/images',
    'chmodFiles' => 0640,
    'chmodFolders' => 0750,
    'filesystemEncoding' => 'UTF-8'
];

$config['resourceTypes'][] = [
    'name' => 'Images',
    'maxSize' => "2M",
    'url' => '/images',
    'allowedExtensions' => 'gif,jpeg,jpg,png,pdf',
    'backend' => 'default'
];
```

When I use one to select an image in CKEditor (using the standard `image2` plugin), it adds a trailing slash after the `baseURL` and before the rest of the path. Browsing and uploading all works correctly, and I can see that internally it's not using extra slashes on folder or file names, yet when I select an image from there in CKEditor, it gains this extra slash:

[image: CKEditor screen shot]

The URL of the selected image should be `/images/apitest/butterfly.png`, but it's returning `/images//apitest/butterfly.png`

I can see that this does not happen on the CKEditor site demos, but I can't see that I'm doing anything different.

It may be that this is happening in other places, but it's common for double-slashes in URLs to be ignored, so it may not be causing any obvious problems.

Comment: Hi. I cannot reproduce this. Could you post also resource type configuration?

Comment: Sorry, I should have included that. Added now.

Comment: I don't get the downvotes on this - it's a clear description of a reproducible problem that has since been determined to be a bug in CKFinder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're missing `"directory"` config key. If you add this then everything will be ok.

Currently it is marked as optional [in the docs](http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3-php/configuration.html#configuration_options_resourceTypes). So it should be updated to either as not optional or make it behave the same with empty `"directory"` config key.

Comment: I've added `'directory' => ''` to my resource configs and it makes no difference; it's still adding the slash. I tried various other strings like `/` and `images`, but that just results in permissions or folder not found errors. Shouldn't the resource simply inherit the backend's `root` property if `directory` is not set or empty in the resource type?

Comment: For now you need to set some subfolder of backend, like: `"directory" => "images"` to remove that extra slash. It is reported as on [CKFinder issue tracker](https://github.com/ckfinder/ckfinder/issues/172).

Comment: For anyone searching for this, this bug has apparently been fixed and will be in the next CKFinder release (3.0.1?).